# efficiently compare two BitArrays of the same length

Tags: c#

How would I do this? I am trying to count when both arrays have the same value of TRUE/1 at the same index. As you can see, my code has multiple bitarrays and is looping through each one and comparing them with a comparisonArray with another loop. It doesn't seem to be very efficient and I need it to be.

```
foreach (bitArrayTuple in bitarryList) { 
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++)
        if (bArrayTuple.Item2[i] && comparisonArray[i])
            bitArrayTuple.Item1++;
}
```

where Item1 is the count and Item2 is a bitarray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much of a way to do this, because `BitArray` doesn't let its internal array leak, and because .NET doesn't have the C++ equivalent of `const` to prevent external modification. You might want to just create your own class from scratch, or, if you feel like hacking, use reflection to get the private field inside the `BitArray`.

Comment: +1, yes, if need is really great then writing own BitArray implementation would be way to go

Answer (score 3):

```
bool equals = ba1.Xor(ba2).OfType<bool>().All(e => !e);
```

Comment: good solution but I think this way we have to clone it first to prevent Xor change ba1.
`((BitArray)ba1.Clone()).Xor(ba2).OfType<bool>().All(e => !e);`

Answer (score 2):

Would this work?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.and%28v=VS.90%29.aspx

It's like the single & operator in C.

Comment: An important caveat with this - it modifies the initial Bitarray to be the product of the and operation

Answer (score 2):

I realize this is an old thread, but I've recently run into a need for this myself and have performed some benchmarks in order to determine which method is fastest:

Firstly, at the moment we can't use `BitArray.Clone()` because of a known bug in Microsoft's code that will not allow cloning of arrays that are larger than `int.MaxValue / 32`. We will need to avoid this method until they have fixed the bug.

With that in mind I have run benchmarks against 5 different implementations, all using the largest `BitArray` I could construct (size of `int.MaxValue`) with alternating bits. I have run the tests with equal and not equal arrays and resulting speed rankings are the same. Here are the implementations:

- Implementation 1: Convert each `BitArray` into a `byte[]` and compare the arrays using the `CompareTo()` method.
- Implementation 2: Convert each `BitArray` into a `byte[]` and compare the each set of `byte`s using an XOR operator (`^`).
- Implementation 3: Convert each `BitArray` into a `int[]` and compare the arrays using the `CompareTo()` method.
- Implementation 4: Convert each `BitArray` into a `int[]` and compare the each set of `int`s using an XOR operator (`^`).
- Implementation 5: Use a `for` loop to iterate over each set of `bool` values and compare

The winner surprised me: **Implementation 3**.

I would have expected Implementation 4 to be the fastest, but as it turns out 3 is significantly faster.

In terms of speed, here are the implementations ranked fastest first:

- Implementation 3
- Implementation 4
- Implementation 2
- Implementation 1
- Implementation 5

Here's my code for implementation 3:

```
public static bool Equals(this BitArray first, BitArray second)
{
    // Short-circuit if the arrays are not equal in size
    if (first.length != second.length)
        return false;
    
    // Convert the arrays to int[]s
    int[] firstInts = new int[(int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)first.Count / 32)];
    first.CopyTo(firstInts, 0);
    int[] secondInts = new int[(int)Math.Ceiling((decimal)second.Count / 32)];
    second.CopyTo(secondInts , 0);

    // Look for differences
    bool areDifferent = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < firstInts.Length && !areDifferent; i++)
        areDifferent = firstInts[i] != secondInts[i];

    return !areDifferent;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending in the number of elements, `BitVector32` may be usable. That would simply be an `Int32` comparison.

If not possible, you will need to get hold of the `int[]` located on the `m_array` private field of each `BitArray`. Then compare the `int[]` of each (which is a comparison of 32 bits at a time).